# Facebook API - How do I create an ad account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am currently trying to create an ad account using fb's api. After checking out their documentation I ended up with this [source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/business/adaccount/). Here it states that we can make a call to
`/{business_id}/adaccount` given the appropriate body to create an ad account, and therefore I went to give it a try.

On my test, I tried sending a POST request to that endpoint:

```
POST {FB_API_PATH}/{business_id}/adaccount?access_token={FB_ACCESS_TOKEN}

BODY
{
    "name": "Test",
    "currency": "USD", 
    "timezone_id": 1, 
    "end_advertiser": "{FB_APP_ID}",
    "media_agency": "{FB_AGENCY_ID}",
    "partner": "NONE",
    "funding_id": "{FB_FUNDING_ID}"
}
```

but ended up getting:

`Unsupported post request. Object with ID '{business_id}' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api`.

***This is not because I'm using an incorrect {business_id}, all of my other test calls that are using the same {business_id} are working perfectly.***

It seems to me that for some reason, I cannot make a call to /adaccount. I went to check the facebook graph explorer and wasn't able to get the autocomplete trigger for that endpoint when inputing the {business_id}.

Am I doing something wrong, or was this endpoint never working and I need to keep doing it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have **Advanced Access** to **business_management** permission.
You can submit app review for advanced access, if it approved, you can call /bm-id/adaccount to create ad account with required parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can't create an ad account on a real FB user. It works with test users well, but you need special permissions from FB to do this on a real user's account.